# WebDriverAgentrRunner failed to initialize for UI testing

Tags: ios, automation

```
Testing failed:
    WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app (462) encountered an error (The test runner failed to initialize for UI testing. (Underlying error: Not authorized for performing UI testing actions.))
** TEST FAILED **
```

After running command

```
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=0836013e8b0dfb9e4c5598974a5d5d5e64761d75' test

-WebDriverAgentRunner gets installed but in terminal displayed error
Testing failed:
    WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app (462) encountered an error (The test runner failed to initialize for UI testing. (Underlying error: Not authorized for performing UI testing actions.))
** TEST FAILED **
```

Not able to run tests using appium

Comment: Running into the same error. Did you find a solution? For me, first it was a entitlements file issue and when i found a work around for that it was this one. A week before that it was working.

Comment: Check this issue, it may be what happened to you: [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/1087)

Comment: Issue was due to facebook webdriver agent runner.When it was fixed test started running successfully :)